# How to force item to be rendered in collapsed mode in a card using Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

When the page containing this code below is rendered, the item shows in expanded mode. How can I force it to be closed?

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col">
<div id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
<div class="card 
   zz_txtblue zz_txt_Bold bg-warning"
   >
   <h6 class="card-header" role="tab" id="A11">
      <a 
         data-toggle="collapse" 
         data-parent="#accordion" 
         href="#collapseOneA11" 
         aria-expanded="false" 
         aria-controls="collapseOneA11" 
         class="d-block">
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-down pull-right"></i> 
      Collapsible Group Item #1
      </a>
   </h6>
   <div id="collapseOneA11" class="collapse show" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="A11">
      <div class="card-body">
         some text
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `show` class from the `collapse` element.

```
      <div class="card zz_txtblue zz_txt_Bold bg-warning">
               <h6 class="card-header" role="tab" id="A11">
                          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOneA11" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOneA11" class="d-block">
                          <i class="fa fa-chevron-down pull-right"></i> 
                          Collapsible Group Item #1
                          </a>
               </h6>
               <div id="collapseOneA11" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="A11">
                      <div class="card-body">
                          some text
                      </div>
               </div>
      </div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/peokOBkvwh

Comment: Perfect. With all these parameters, it is confusing! Thank you for your help. I will mark this as the answer in 5 minutes (as soon as the site lets me do so).